# typeahead autocomplete doesn't work sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I implemented Typeahead autocomplete with Rails 4 using elasticsearch, searchkick and bootstrap.
It works fine when I reload the webpage, but doesn't work when the cached page is loaded.
I wonder where should I start to fix the problem.

Here is the snippet of my js code:

```
$ ->
  $('#profile_search').typeahead
  name: "profile"
  remote: "/profiles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
Here is my working variant.

```
remote:{
         url: '/profiles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
               filter: function(parsedResponse) {
               return parsedResponse.data;
               }
            },
    prefetch: '/profiles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY';
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I updated my code.
However, the problem was in turbolinks. 
It worked fine after I turned off turbolinks.